# Проблема с библиотекой vk_api python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот код моей заготовки бота для бесед:

```py
import time
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token="тут был токен")

longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, тут был id группы)
vk = vk_session.get_api()
print("Бот запущен")

# Основной цикл
while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            if event.from_chat:
                vk.messages.send(chat_id=event.chat_id, message='Ваш текст', random_id=1)
```

Как мне получить, что именно было в новом сообщении?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Stackoverflow - это не форум, здесь не принято делать в заголовке пометку о решении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `event.object['text']`